# How can I add a custom permalink to a term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

How can I make a taxonomy term have a custom permalink? (on a term basis, e.g. `/anything/here` for a taxonomy called `food` and a term called `burrito`)

I don't think there's much more to explain so, my ideas are:

- `pre_get_posts`, `$_SERVER` to detect url saved against an options table.
- Register hidden post type that matches each term id. Still how to create custom nested permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to what you are after here, but I was simply filtering by a meta key.

```
add_action('init', 'add_custom_meta_url');
function add_custom_meta_url() {
    global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('food');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('food/([^/]+)','index.php?food=$matches[1]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false); // This should really be done in a plugin activation
}
```

And then apply this to the index query through query vars (you'd have to target the taxonomy values instead of the custom meta and adjust the compare to =):

```
add_action('parse_query', 'apply_custom_meta_to_query');
function apply_custom_meta_to_query(&$query) {
    if (isset($query->query['food'])) {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'food';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $query->query['food'];
        $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = 'LIKE';
    }
}
```

There could be more efficient ways to do this, but keep looking at `wp_rewrite`, as that's the WordPress way to handle pretty URLs rather than try to hack into the flow of things.

Good luck!